# Are Wednesday church services scriptural?

Tags: biblical-basis

Are Wednesday church services scriptural? I believe I have seen scriptures that relate to Wednesday services, but I can not remember where.

Answer (score 9):

A church service is a gathering of believers who have an intent of glorifying God with the Word, prayer, worship, and breaking of bread, or a smaller version with just one or two of these aspects. That is allowable any day of the week. For the believer, every day is an opportunity to glorify God, with the gathering of the saints and without.

Is it scriptural? Romans 14:5 tells us, "One person esteems one day above another; another esteems every day alike. Let each be fully convinced in his own mind."

I thank God that our church here in Costa Mesa has Bible studies every day of the week, so we may go as often as we need the refreshing breezes from off His holy hill.

Answer (score 7):

The specific day of the week isn't mentioned in Scripture, but you can imply from Scripture that we should assemble regularly, so they're not *un-Scriptural*.

From [The Origin of Sunday and Wednesday Evening Services](http://www.learnthebible.org/the-origin-of-sunday-and-wednesday-evening-services.html)

> The mid-week meeting had its beginnings in prayer meetings that were
>   occasionally mentioned before 1800 but became popular through the
>   efforts of Charles Finney and D. L. Moody in the 1800's.
>
> ...
>
> The apostolic church often met on a daily basis: "And daily in the
>   temple, and in every house, they ceased not to teach and preach Jesus
>   Christ" (Acts 5:42 ). Hebrews 10:25 tells us, "Not forsaking the
>   assembling of ourselves together, as the manner of some is; but
>   exhorting one another: and so much the more, as ye see the day
>   approaching."

Comment: What about the next: "On the **first day of every week** each one of you is to put aside and save, as he may prosper, so that no collections be made when I come". From 1 Corinthians 16 (NASB).

Answer (score -3):

In six days God created the heavens and the earth....and on the seventh day he rested.

God sanctified and hallowed only one day...the seventh. The biblical creation story is very clear on this day and it is also reinforced very specifically in the ten commandments (ie an entire commandment is dedicated to it)

Jesus worshiped on the seventh day...as was his custom.

Christians are followers of jesus model...Jesus did not model any other day of sabbath worship. Jesus also regularly referred to the old testament writings for his teachings (he did not ignore them or rewrite them).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Comment: Welcome to the site. As a new user, please know that down votes aren't necessarily in opposition to your scriptural understanding – instead, votes have to do with how well the question is answered. In this case, I don't believe the question is asking about the Sabbath per se; the question is whether it's proper or biblically-supported for Christians to gather on other days of the week (Wednesday). That could mean for Bible study groups, classes, etc... Hope this helps!